# SelectionChanged fired also on nested controls?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Sorry for misleading title, I'll try to explain better.
I've a TabControl like this:

```
<dragablz:TabablzControl SelectionChanged="MainTabs_SelectionChanged" x:Name="MainTabs">
```

where inside I've different `TabItems`, I need to fire the event `MainTabs_SelectionChanged` each time the user change the `TabItem`, this working but the event is fired also when the selection of a combobox, available inside the tabitem, change.

This is the `ComboBox`:

```
<ComboBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Groups}" 
                                              Margin="8,0,8,16" DisplayMemberPath="Name" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedGroup}" />
```

why happen this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> why happen this?

Because `SelectionChanged` is a *routed* event.

**Routed Events Overview:** https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/routed-events-overview

You could use the `OriginalSource` property to determine whether a tab was selected:

```
private void MainTabs_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.OriginalSource == MainTabs)
    {
        //do your thing
    }
}
```